# How to add up a column depending on data from another column

Tags: oracle, functions, aggregate

I have a table which has results and a table that has `band_name` and `band_id`.

Now I need to create a query which will add up the total points for each band and display the band name and ID, so far I have

```
SELECT
  SUM(placing.points) AS sumpoints,
  band.band_id
FROM placing, band
GROUP BY band.band_id
ORDER BY SUM(placing.points) DESC
```

The results end up giving me each unique `band_id` but the total of all the points on all bands as oppose to the bands points.

Comment: Can you post your table structure?  Right now, you are not joining the `placing` and the `band` tables on any column.  You are creating a cartesian result since there is no join between the two tables.

Comment: So you are aware that the information is still there right?

Comment: Ah yeah, never mind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are not joining your two tables based on `band_id`, as a result you are creating a [Cartesian product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29#Cross_join).  When you create this cartesian product, you are combining each row from your `placing` table to each row in the `band` table.

For example, if you have data similar to the following:

```
create table band
(
  band_id number
);

insert into band values (1);
insert into band values (2);
insert into band values (3);
insert into band values (4);
insert into band values (5);

create table placing
(
  band_id number,
  points number
);

insert into placing values (1, 10);
insert into placing values (1, 2);
insert into placing values (2, 1);
insert into placing values (3, 3);
insert into placing values (3, 89);
insert into placing values (4, 45);
insert into placing values (5, 63);
```

And you query the data without a join on the `band_id` column:

```
SELECT
  placing.points,
  band.band_id
FROM placing, band;
```

You are generating data similar to:

```
| POINTS | BAND_ID |
|--------|---------|
|     10 |       1 |
|      2 |       1 |
|      1 |       1 |
|      3 |       1 |
|     89 |       1 |
|     45 |       1 |
|     63 |       1 |
```

See [Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/e19ea/1). As you can see `band_id = 1` now has every single `point` value from the `placing` table even though your really only have `points = 10` and `points=2`.

In order to get the correct result, you need to `JOIN` the two tables on the `band_id` column. Your query will be similar to the following:

```
SELECT
  SUM(p.points) AS sumpoints,
  b.band_id
FROM placing p
INNER JOIN band b
  on p.band_id = b.band_id
GROUP BY b.band_id
ORDER BY SUM(p.points) DESC;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/e19ea/2). This will give a result of:

```
| SUMPOINTS | BAND_ID |
|-----------|---------|
|        92 |       3 |
|        63 |       5 |
|        45 |       4 |
|        12 |       1 |
|         1 |       2 |
```